# Could not fetch/save url ... [Errno 14] curl#35 - "TCP connection reset by peer"

Tags: rhel, docker

I tried to install [docker-ce](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-repository) on RedHat7 but I got this error:

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager, versionlock
adding repo from: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
grabbing file https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
Could not fetch/save url https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo to file /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo: [Errno 14] curl#35 - "TCP connection reset by peer"
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs when you are using SSL inspection between the clients and internet. If that’s the case, you should add an exclusion for this host.